# lotus formula to find all numbers between two numbers

Tags: formula, lotus

Ive got two fields that calculate the week number of two dates start date and end date. So I have two field called FirstWeek and LastWeek. I want to find all the numbers between the FirstWeek and LastWeek and put those in another field.

For instance firstweek = 35
lastweek = 39

I want field weeks= 35, 36, 37, 38, 39

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  I would like to use formula if at all possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Please see [mcve] and [ask] for how to ask good questions.

Comment: The answers here unlikely to be any better than what you've already received over on the IBM Lotus Notes/Domino 8.5 Forum

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/ShowMyTopicsAllFlatweb/041e0cdf49882a4f8525817f004cf406?OpenDocument

Comment: Your real problem, which you didn't mention above, is still with the intervals that span from one year into the next. Whether you do it with two concatenatedl lists from "01" to "52"/"53" and @Subset or with a loop, you have to take into account whether the current year has 52 numbered weeks of 53. The rest is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In @Formula language you also have For loop. If you have number field **firstweek** and number field **lastweek** you can create number field **weeks**, my advice is that this is a multivalue field, and try this formula:

```
REM {firstweek_date is the date field from which you are calculating the value of firstweek number};

year_firstweek := @Year(firstweek_date);

REM {lastweek_date is the date field from which you are calculating the value of lastweek number};

year_lastweek :=@Year(lastweek_date);

REM {if the year diff is one then the first value of weeks field is first week};
REM {NOTE: I took that every year has 52 weeks.};
REM {If this is not OK then for number_of_weeks_in_year set the value in a same way as you are doing with firstweek but for date @Date(year_firstweek ; 12 ; 31 ).};

REM {If the dates are in same Year then as written before you can use the same logic};

REM {Otherwise I set field week to 0};

@If((year_lastweek-year_firstweek) = 1;
            @Do(
                FIELD weeks := firstweek;
                number_of_weeks_in_year := 52;
                @For(n := firstweek+1; n <= number_of_weeks_in_year; n := n + 1;FIELD weeks := weeks:n);
                @For(n := 1; n <= lastweek; n := n + 1;FIELD weeks := weeks:n)
            );
        (year_lastweek-year_firstweek) = 0;
            @Do(

                FIELD weeks := firstweek;
                @For(n := firstweek+1; n <= lastweek; n := n + 1;FIELD weeks := weeks:n)
            );
        FIELD weeks := 0
)
```

Comment: This works great.  Problem I am having now is if the first week is 2017 and the last week is in 2018 it only picks up the first week.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the maximum difference in years, from first week till last week? Can first week for example be in 2016 and last week in 2020 or the range is always max. one year?

Comment: It would probably only span 1 year.  2017 to 2018

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope the updated code will help you to solve your issue.